# How to call all javascript member functions in an array? [node.js]

Tags: node.js, object, iteration

I want to iterate through and call all member functions associated to **"os"**

```
var os = require('os'); 
var keye = Object.keys(os);
keye.forEach(f => os.f());
```

> Prototype:

```
{ endianness: [Function: getEndianness],
  hostname: [Function: getHostname],
  loadavg: [Function: getLoadAvg],
  uptime: [Function: getUptime],
  freemem: [Function: getFreeMem],
  totalmem: [Function: getTotalMem],
  cpus: [Function: getCPUs],
  type: [Function: getOSType],
  release: [Function: getOSRelease],
  networkInterfaces: [Function: getInterfaceAddresses],
  arch: [Function],
  platform: [Function],
  tmpdir: [Function],
  tmpDir: [Function],
  getNetworkInterfaces: [Function: deprecated],
  EOL: '\r\n' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
Object.keys(os).forEach(function (key) {
    if (typeof os[key] === 'function') {
        console.log(key, os[key]());
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you also answer this question please?  [Distinguish b/w two or more TCP clients in nodejs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276246/distinguish-b-w-two-or-more-tcp-clients-in-nodejs)