# Distinguish b/w two or more TCP clients in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, client, tcpserver

isn't there any Unique ID or something for every client?
suppose I want use this echo server to echo message received from one client to all connected clients:

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer();
server.on('connection', function (server_socket) {
    console.log('client connected');
    server_socket.write('hello client! Say something.');

    server_socket.pipe(server_socket);

    server_socket.on('end', function () {
        console.log('client disconnected');
    });
});

server.listen(80, 'localhost');
server.on('listen', function () {
    console.log('Listning for connections:');
});

server.on('error', function (error) {
    console.dir(error);
});
```

I tried Everything i knew, i.e
Events like connection,request etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your purpose you do not really need of an UID, you can try to keep all the active connections in an array and broadcast any data when needed.

```
var connections = [];

server.on('connection', function (socket) {

    connections.push(socket);

    socket.write('SOMETHING');

    // Broadcast some message
    connections.forEach(function (connection) {
        if (connection !== socket) { // Filter connections
            connection.write('SOMETHING ELSE');
        }
    });

    // Clean up closed connections
    socket.on('close', function () {
        var index = connections.indexOf(socket); // Get socket index

        connections.splice(index, 1); // Remove the socket from the connections
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would use socket.io this would be pretty easy. You would need to check the property id of the socket-object:

```
server.on('connection', function(socket) {
   console.log(socket.id + " connected");
});
```

As long as you use raw sockets you have the option to generate a id on connect, where the function *generateUniqueSocketId()* could return a GUID or something unique to distinguish between the connections:

```
server.on('connection', function(socket) {
   socket.myConnectionId = generateUniqueSocketId();
});
```